# Visual Studio 2008 conversion wizard pops up for 2008 project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wizard

Visual Studio 2008 Conversion Wizard opens up whenever i try to open a VS 2008 solution using VS2008.
It is not a converted project, but one that has been created using VS2008. If I click continue, it is checking out all the files in the solution from source control. Could some someone please help on how to fix this and not have visual studio 2008 conversion wizard pop up for 2008 solutions?

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2008 SPK1 installed, Visual Studio 2010 Installed and Visual Studio 2010 SPK1 installed. My other team mates with same installation have different versions of C# installed when i check their visual studio information and are able to open the solutions just fine. I tried repairing the 2008 and its service pack, uninstalled all versions of visual studio and reinstalled with no progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. My local workspace was corrupt. Deleting everything on the local and getting new files from the source control fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create a brand new solution, close and reopen VS2008 and see if it does the same for that.

If yes then you've got a problem with your installation.

If no then you know there's something messed up in your other solution/project.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I tried it and was able to create and open a solution in VS2008. The other solutions that I am not able to open, are opening on other computers of my teammates with no issue. The only difference that i noted is the version of the C# is different on my machine and theirs. Any suggestion on why the C# on two machines is different with same installations? or is there anything that is causing my version of C# to be different from theirs?

Comment: Well what exact version numbers are you talking about? e.g. I have VS2010 C# Express installed, the .NET framework version is 4.0.30319 SP1 Rel, and the VS2010 version is 10.0.40219.1 SP1 Rel.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
Version 9.0.30729.4462 QFE
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 3.5 SP1

Installed Edition: Professional

Microsoft Visual Basic 2008   91605-270-0801147-60476
Microsoft Visual C# 2008   91605-270-0801147-60476
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008   91605-270-0801147-60476
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Tools for Office   91605-270-0801147-60476
Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008   91605-270-0801147-60476
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB947888)   KB947888

Comment: Looks like you have a weird version of VS. Try to follow solution from here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/vstsstart/thread/a69e0e0f-19d4-4f2c-90ef-64a980ef22f6

Comment: Hi, I tried that and it did not resolve the problem. Any other suggestion please?